# How would I place a message under an image when hovering on the image?(Partially done)

Tags: html, css

So, the title asks the whole question pretty much. I just can't get it to work like i'd like. I want it so when I hover over the image the message displays right under it but I can't seem to get that to work. Any suggestions would help!

Here's what I got!

```css
html, body {
 background-color: #0A6DFF;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.cont img{
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 2%;
 border: 5px solid black; 
}

.gsFour {
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 margin: 2%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.gsFive {
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 margin: 2%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.gsSeven {
 position: relative;
 display: none;
 margin: 2%;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#imgFour:hover ~ .gsFour {
 display: inline;
}

#imgFive:hover ~ .gsFive {
 display: inline;
}

#imgSeven:hover ~ .gsSeven {
 display: inline;
}

#imgFour:hover {
 border: 5px solid white; 
}

#imgFive:hover {
 border: 5px solid white; 
}

#imgSeven:hover {
 border: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Phones</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <center>
   <p><h1>Hover your mouse over the images!</h1></p>
   <hr>
      <div class="cont">
         <img id="imgFour" src="imgs/gsFour.jpg">
         <img id="imgFive" src="imgs/gs5.jpg">
         <img id="imgSeven" src="imgs/gs7.jpg">
         <br>
         <p class="gsFour">This is a galaxy s4!</p>
         <p class="gsFive">This is a galaxy s5!</p>
         <p class="gsSeven">This is a galaxy gs7!</p>
      </div>
   </center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is honestly the best I could come up with so far. Thanks again!

Comment: The message is displayed as you wanted when an image is hovered in your above snippet though.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem Yes but not right under the image. It displays the message in the middle no matter what image i'm hovering over.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2Lmo37nf/



check this

Comment: Some things to note; the `<center>` tag is deprecated (a long time ago), you have a `<h1>` inside a `<p>` tag which semantically doesn't make sense as it's a heading not a paragraph.

Comment: @AhsanAzizAbbasi This is partially what I need but this is top to bottom. I need left to right.

Comment: simply remove <br> tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="cont">
           <!-- wrap img and p tag inside 'posion' div --> 
            <div class="posion">
            <img id="imgFour" src="imgs/gsFour.jpg">
            <p class="gsFour">This is a galaxy s4!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="posion">
            <img id="imgFive" src="imgs/gs5.jpg">
            <p class="gsFive">This is a galaxy s5!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="posion">
            <img id="imgSeven" src="imgs/gs7.jpg">
            <p class="gsSeven">This is a galaxy gs7!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
<style>
/* new add css*/
.posion {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.posion img:hover ~ p{
     position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 96%;
    left: 2%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY* what I needed! Thank you so much!
-
EXACTLY - I still need to adjust the position like make top equal to 100% not 50%.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the `position:absolute` property on the element, in this case the class `.gsFour`. Take a look at the fiddle below and see what you think.

https://jsfiddle.net/37L19t6L/

As I've mentioned in the comments, you should reconsider your use of the `<center>` element seeing as this has been deprecated see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

If you need more information on how to use positioning in CSS, [here](https://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101) is a great article, which helped me a long time ago.